# Multi-navigation robot in RViz

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I just finished to built one navigation robot and it worked perfectly in RViz, and now I want to build another navigation robot, and show two robots navigate simultaneously in RViz, and robot can communicate with each other.  Is it possible to do this?  and is there any tutorial or related knowledge?   thank you very much in advance! (the robot use robot_localization and move_base package) (NOT in simulator )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316394/multi-navigation-robot-in-rviz/) by [Clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/37771/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes! It is feasible!
Just add the prefix for each robot's tf and link with the same map!

Check this [video](https://youtu.be/xToON3lmIzA)

The TF tree should looks like this

```
          /map
   |--------|--------|
/robot1  /robot2  /robot3
```

---

Originally posted by [PowerfulMing](https://answers.ros.org/users/40080/powerfulming/) with karma: 40 on 2019-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/37771/clark/) on 2019-02-26**:
But for the topic publishing, the topic name can be the same? For example, move_base package will publish the /cmd_vel topic to robot, then how could it know which robot to publish? or do I need to change the topic name like robot_x/cmd_vel ?   thanks

**Comment by [PowerfulMing](https://answers.ros.org/users/40080/powerfulming/) on 2019-04-07**:
In the launch file, change the name space prefix